# Mac OS cocoa. Advice for creating custom views

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift3

I need the advice of experienced developers.
The question is, how best to create custom views with or without xib?
Can there be links to useful resources, where does it discuss?

Comment: Search [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) for `NSView` and you'll find [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the `NSView` documentation. I prefer using existing views in my custom `NSView` subclasses and laying them out using auto layout in code.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html